# Is [0,1] x $y$ a measurable set in the Borel algebra?

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

Let's say I have a joint distribution $p(x,y)$ where $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm wondering if $[0,1] \times y$ is measurable in this case.

It seems like it shouldn't be, but I came across https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579565/why-is-this-set-a-borel-set-on-r2 and it's giving me doubts.

Comment: Evidently you are using "$[0,1]\times y$" as a shorthand for "$[0,1]\times \{y\}.$" This suggests you doubt either that (a) $\{y\}$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ or (b) the Cartesian product of measurable sets is measurable.  Which one is troubling you? Please note, too, that this issue has nothing whatsoever to do with $p$ because in your title you specify that measurability is with respect to the Borel algebra.

Comment: I guess my wording is wrong. More precisely, I'm wondering if $[0,1] \times \{ y \}$ is in the product algebra.

Comment: It is in the product algebra if each component is in its respective algebra.  So, which component are you uncertain about?

Comment: $\{y \}$. It's not a measurable on it's own, right? Otherwise the marginal density evaluated at $y$ would be a probability?

Comment: Please don't confuse densities with probabilities: they're quite different.  As far as measurability goes, $\{y\}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\left((-\infty, y)\cup(y,\infty)\right)$ constructs $\{y\}$ in terms of finite (therefore countable) unions and intersections of open sets.